# How to remove faucet handle for cartridge replacement

Tags: faucet, plumbing-fixture, taps

I have an unknown brand kitchen mixer tap that is dripping from the cold lever but I can't see how to replace the ceramic cartridge. Normally there's a tiny screw under the lever, often covered by a plastic cap, but I can't see one on this tap.

How do I get the lever off to access the ceramic cartridge?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If the brand is unknown, how will you get the right replacement cartridge?

Comment: Can you unscrew the lever from the handle base?

Comment: @isherwood I have tried, but it wouldn't shift using the amount of force I was willing to try.

Comment: @DanielGriscom as soon as I can get the existing cartridge out there shouldn't be an issue being a replacement.